# Can't seem to get a method's value in another method

Tags: javascript, object

```
//form handler
var form=document.getElementsByName('contact-form')[0];
var errDis=document.getElementById('err-dis');

form.onsubmit=function()
{
    var err=false;
    var ele=form.elements;
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
        if(ele[i].className.indexOf('verified')==-1)
        {
            ele[i].errBlink();
            err=true; 
            continue;
        }

        if(ele[i].id=='mailer_email')
        {
            //console.log(ele[i].value);    
        }  
    }

    if(!err)
    {
        var conForm=new Form(form);

        conForm.submit;
    }
    else
    {
        errDis.innerHTML="Submit Again With Correct And Proper Information";   
    }
    return false;
}  

//Form Object


Object.size=function(obj)
    {
        var size=0;
        for(var key in obj)
        {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }
        return size;
    };



var Form=function(form)
{
    this.form=form;
    this.values=getFormValues();
    this.queryString=getQuery();
    this.submit=console.log(this.queryString);//for test
}

//returns associative array of name=value as key=pair value where name is value of name attribute
function getFormValues()
{
    var vallArr=new Array();
    var form_ele=this.form.elements;
    for(var i=0;i<form_ele.length;i++)
    {
        var ele=form_ele[i];
        vallArr[ele.name]=ele.value.trim();  
    }
    return vallArr;
}


function getQuery()
{
    var valArr=this.values;
    console.log(this.values);
    var queryStr='';
    var len=Object.size(this.values);
    var i=0;
    for(var key in this.values)
    {
        queryStr+=key+'='+this.values[key];
        if(i<(len-1)) queryStr+='&';
        i++;
    }
    return queryStr;
}
```

I created a object for Form Handling but when i run getQuery method, the method doesn't seem to get value of this.values method. It always returns undefined. I am doing some mistake here but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Where and How are you using `Form()`?

Comment: Change `this.queryString=getQuery();` to `this.queryString=getQuery;`

Comment: yeah that might work

Comment: it didn't now it just returns the function itself

Answer (score 2):

You defined your method in the global scope so the `this` keyword inside the `getQuery()` method points to the global object (which is `window` inside a browser).

You need to declare the method as part of the `Form` constructor:

```
Form.prototype.getQuery = function () {
    // ...place your logic here...
}
```

I would recommend you to look further into prototyping in javascript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype
- http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: @hengecyche Thats because you defined a `var form` inside the global scope. So `this.form` is not referencing to the form object of the Form constructor, but to the globally defined `var form`.

Comment: though when i did this.querystring=function(){} like this console.log returned function querystring()

Comment: @hengecyche That is because you assigned the function to the member of the `Form` instance. When @Alexander mentioned to do this as a solution of your problem, he meant that you call `this.queryString` instead of `getQuery`.